# Why did Madara have Rinnegan before activating it and nobody noticed?

Tags: naruto

While I was watching Episode 322 of Naruto Shippuden, I found what I guess is a mistake:

First look at the picture:

[image]

Since Madara came, he was using only Sharingan, and this can be seen until 07:43 in the picture, while he was dodging Gaara's sand attacks. However, when Naruto was above him with an Odama Rasengan, Madara suddenly could be seen with the Rinnegan on his eyes (07:45), and nobody noticed it like if it was a mistake. It should have been normal Sharingan.

Then, at 08:17, Madara was using the Mangekyou Sharingan, since he activated it after Naruto's attack to invoke the Susanoo.

And after that, at around 10:04, Madara was targeted by a Rasenshuriken, hence he had to activate the Rinnegan, and that was at 10:06. It was the first time that he did it since he came to life with Edo Tensei, and that could be confirmed from everybody's reaction when they saw his Rinnegan at around 10:56 ("Why does he have the Rinnegan?").

**Was it a mistake that they drew Madara with the Rinnegan at 07:45?**

Comment: Good observation but I think this is a duplicate I just don't see the other question.

Comment: Yeah i. Noticed it at the first time And yeah it's a mistake they probably didn't pay attentions so yeah

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Yes, it was a mistake (and yes, [I noticed it before you did](http://chat.stackexchange.com/transcript/message/10728598#10728598), ask the regulars at chat =P), nice job spotting it!

In the manga, that specific scene doesn't exist (the part where he looks up at the Rasengan), so apparently the animators or the editors simply made him with the Rinnegan for some reason.

Comment: The animators may have drawn things correctly, in sequence, but the _editors_ may have reused bits of footage (commonly done - saves time and effort) and missed the eyes. Another reason why copy-paste can bite you ;)